# Is it possible to glob a directory in iOS and have the results cached by the OS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-io, nsfilemanager, glob

Many methods of reading from a filesystem using `NSFileManager` and lower level APIs on iOS involve built-in caching, so reading from directories that haven't changed can be quite fast, even if there's lots of items in the directories.

I have a situation where I want to be able to enumerate files in a directory using a glob:

i.e. the folder has files named like this:

```
1-1-0.png
1-2-0.png
1-3-0.png
1-3-1.png
2-2-1.png
5-1-1.png
5-1-2.png
5-2-1.png
5-3-0.png
6-1-1.png
...
1501-5-2.png
```

I might want to get all filenames matching `5-*-1.png`, which would give me back `5-1-1.png` and `5-2-1.png`.

Loading the whole directory listing then doing the globbing in RAM is pretty straightforward, but is there a method for doing this at an OS level that would have caching built-in, so repeated calls to the same glob would give cached (faster) results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `glob()` function as outlined in this gist: https://gist.github.com/bkyle/293959

```
#include <glob.h> 

+ (NSArray*) arrayWithFilesMatchingPattern: (NSString*) pattern inDirectory: (NSString*) directory { 
  NSMutableArray* files = [NSMutableArray array];
  glob_t gt;
  NSString* globPathComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@", pattern];
  NSString* expandedDirectory = [directory stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
  const char* fullPattern = [[expandedDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: globPathComponent] UTF8String];
  if (glob(fullPattern, 0, NULL, &gt) == 0) {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<gt.gl_matchc; i++) {
          size_t len = strlen(gt.gl_pathv[i]);
          NSString* filename = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] stringWithFileSystemRepresentation: gt.gl_pathv[i] length: len];
          [files addObject: filename];
      }
  }
  globfree(&gt);
  return [NSArray arrayWithArray: files];
}
```